# Mean.js - Dependancies Missing

Tags: heroku, gulp, meanjs

I am using the MeanJS (https://github.com/meanjs/mean) framework, running on Heroku.  When I try to run the application I get errors like:

> Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb/legacy'

I am running in production mode (NODE_ENV=production).

The question I have is, it seems like gulpfile.js (when running the task prod) calls the task lint which calls the task eslint.  But when I look at the packages.json file, I see that eslint-config-airbnb is only included in the devDependancies (and not dependancies).  Now I tired to add it to dependancies, but I still get the same error about the missing module.

I'm new to MEAN.js, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you run the `gulp prod` command ?

Comment: It looks like gulp prod is set in the packages.json (under scripts), but also I see gulp dev.  I'm new to MEAN and Node in general, so I'm still not 100% sure how gulp gets called in this case.